# Are there any existing ontologies that model engineering data?

Tags: reference-request, ontology

Are there any existing ontologies available for "engineering" data?

By "engineering" I mean pertaining to the fields of electrical, mechanical, thermal, etc., engineering.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the motivation for your question?

Comment: @tmaric I wast looking for a structured data resource for engineering, so far have found wikidata and dbpedia but not sure how engineering specific they are and what level of completeness exists in either of them.

Comment: I'm asking because there's an effort at the Uni where I work to define a metadata standard for (mechanical) engineering, which is the answer to your question, so I would also like to know if there is something out there already.

Comment: @tmaric good to know that, so what level of completion is that project, is it available to the public or only for internal use?

Comment: We are just starting with this, but there are some preliminary results from Stuttgart: https://www.ub.uni-stuttgart.de/forschen-publizieren/forschungsdatenmanagement/projekte/dipl_ing/index.en.html  There is some information in English but a lot of the info is in German.

Comment: Here are the slides from that project in English: https://www.ub.uni-stuttgart.de/forschen-publizieren/forschungsdatenmanagement/projekte/dipl_ing/materials/output/MTSR2018_14_SchemberaIglezakis_EngMeta.pdf